# Отладка Java-программ

Tags: отладка, windows, macos, java, intellij-idea

1. Как узнать, сколько раз исполняется данный отрезок кода?
2. Как останавливать исполнение, только если значение переменной равно чему-то?
3. Как останавливать исполнение, только если кто-то выкидывает Exception, кроме брейкпоинта на Exception.class?

Comment: @KutaBeach, о *языке программирования* (и ОС) мы сами должны догадаться?

Comment: исправил, но мне казалось это везде стандартно должно быть, и если от чего и зависит то от среды разработки в некоторой степени.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Профилировщик](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)) в помощь, он вам еще и расскажет за какое время он выполняется. 
    По идее можно профайлить любой код, если конечно он не заппускает другую программу, так    как тогда придется обрабатывать и её. Вот вроде неплохой [java профайлер](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html).
2. Вот скажем точка оставноки сделанная вручную на С++.

   ```
   if (a == 1)
   {
   cin >> a;
   cout << "Точка остановки здесь."
   }
   ```
3. Поставить breakpoint в блоке catch или написать там e.printStackTrace()

Comment: @igumnov, ТС уточнил, что его интересует Java (не С++) в IDE IntellijIdea.

Comment: Спасибо, дело в том что я не могу менять код. А можно вообще профайлить исполнение тестов Мейвена? И еще вопрос: я могу при дебаге печатать значение переменной куда-нибудь? Вопрос уточнил см PS.

Comment: @avp Да пока я копался в окне ответа, тред изменился. Сейчас добавлю еще что-нибудь.

Comment: Я еще не понимаю как вы пытаетесь дебагать не меняя кода? Вам в любом случае придется написать туда какой-то код, который выводит нужную Вам дебаг информацию в данный момент, а не ту что предлагает IDE.

Comment: я могу исполнять любые выражение через Watches в IntellijIdea. Однако не понимаю как мне сохранять результаты исполнения.